# Placing a string in memory and saving it later

Tags: c#, string, performance, memory, streamwriter

I have a program that creates a huge string, too large for `StringBuilder` to handle. I want to store it in memory, then, at a later date, save it to a user defined directory.
I have tried a `StreamWriter` but I need to declare the directory as I create it and that is problem because I get the directory later on, if the user selects the "Save to text file".

Basically I need it to:

-Create instance of whatever it is (public and in a class scope, can not be in a method scope)

-Add a string to instance

-Then, later on, whenever the user decides, save that to a file. I am aware it will take up a large amount of RAM and I believe it will only be around 50-100Mb, which isn't too bad.

```
public class ImageProcessor
{
    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
    StreamWriter sw;
    public Bitmap Rendering(string bmpPath)
    {
        sw = new StreamWriter(ms, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8);
        using (ms)
                  sw.Write(Convert.ToString(ArGBformat)); //Error is here
    }
}
```

`

Comment: How did you determine it's too big for a `StringBuilder`?  The only [limiation on StringBuilder is `IntMax` (2.1GB)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.stringbuilder.maxcapacity.aspx).

Comment: @ErikPhilips I get an "OutOfMemoryException" related to the `StringBuilder`

Comment: Why not use a `MemoryStream` and then when the user decides to save it, save it to a file?

Comment: @Tim How would I go about doing that? Can you show me the snippet in the answer selection?

Comment: Take a look at the `StreamWriter` overload that doesn't require a filename - [StreamWriter Constructor (Stream)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/wtbhzte9%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).  This takes a stream as the parameter; you'd probably have to read the MemoryStream to write it to a file.  There's also an overload that takes a stream and an encoding as well.

Comment: You don't mention framework version, but starting in version 4.0 the .net framework no longer requires memory streams, string builder instances to use contiguous memory. You can very easily hit an out of memory condition on the older versions that work great starting the 4.0

Comment: What does this gargantuan string consist of?  Perhaps there are some design changes that can avoid the whole issue.

Comment: @SteveWellens It contains a `Color.FromArGb();` of all the pixels in an image.

Comment: @Rynoh97 Color.FromArGb(); doesn't return a String.

Comment: @SteveWellens When I use a `StringBuilder` it worked. Plus I can go `Convert.ToString(Color.FromArgb));` if need be.

Comment: @Rynoh97 what are you doing with a string of ints? Are you trying to serialize the image? If so, don't bother serializing it (and preferably in a better format) until it's actually time to save. I can't imagine what manipulations you are doing on the string that can't be done better on the image or some sort of bit array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a code snippet that may help you. I just tested it in VS 2012:

```
using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream)
{

    StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(ms, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8)
    sw.WriteLine("This is a test.");
    sw.WriteLine("This is a second line.");
    sw.Flush();

    using (FileStream fs = new FileStream("Test.txt", FileMode.Create))
    {
        ms.CopyTo(fs);
    }

    sw.Close();
}
```

The file contents are:

```
This is a test.
This is a second line.
```

You'll want to modify this to fit your program's design, but the basic idea is using a `StreamWriter` to write the text to the `MemoryStream`, and then writing the `MemoryStream` to the file with the `MemoryStream.CopyTo` method (which takes a `Stream`).

Be careful with how you construct things - if you close the `StreamWriter` it will close the `MemoryStream` as well (the first time I tested this I had the `StreamWriter` in a `using` block inside the `MemoryStream` using block, and then got an error trying to access a closed stream).

Hopefully this will at least get you going in the right direction.

**EDIT**

You'll need to initialize the `StreamWriter` in a method, not as a field variable.

Something like this:

```
public class ImageProcessor
{

    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
    StreamWriter sw;

    public Bitmap Rendering(string bmpPath)
    {

        sw = new StreamWriter(ms, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello Tim. Thank you for all your time and effort and you code looks like it will work. Only problem is that the `StreamWriter` isn't public, same goes with the `MemoryStream`. I need to be able to add it to memory in one method and then save in the another.

Comment: Are the methods in the same class?  If so, make the `StreamWriter` and `MemoryStream` class level variables.  If they're in different classes, another option is to still make them class level variables with public properties to expose them.  A third option is to move all of that logic into a separate class that is used by the other classes in the application.

Comment: I tried that but then I can no longer use `StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(ms, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8);` because sw is undefined even though defined right above it.

Comment: Can you update your question with the code? I'm having a hard time picturing what you're trying to describe.

Comment: Check above.Thank you.

Comment: See my edit.  Basically, you can't reference other fields in field variable initialization.

Comment: Okay fixed everything but now it gives me an exception saying `ObjectDisposedException` even though I haven't closed it.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/52450/discussion-between-tim-and-rynoh97)